# How to split a text file into a fixed width file in tcsh?

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

I need to read a text file and make it fit X amount of columns.

For example, if my text.txt contains:

```
ABCDEFGHIJK
```

the resulting file for a width of 4 should be:

```
ABCD
EFGH
IJK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
$ echo ABCDEFGHIJK | sed -r 's/(....)/\1\n/g'
ABCD
EFGH
IJK
```